# Wifi trouble since 10.9.2 update

Tags: macos, wifi, airport

Since I updated my system from 10.9.1 to 10.9.2, I now have a very annoying  WiFi issue : when I click on the airport icon on the top bar, the WiFi networks are no longueur scanned and I sometimes have to wait up to 5 minutes to see networks around me.

Those two have been taken with a small interval :

[image: First screen shot]

[image: Second screen shot]

Any clue ?

Comment: Do you have a lots of unused WiFi that were saved in your profile?

Comment: @Buscar웃 22, gonna clean-up.